# Getting the wrong results from NArgMax

Tags: mathematical-optimization, splines

Consider the following code

```
U={0.,0.,0.,0.,0.00817368,0.0122626,0.0163535,0.0208655,0.025796,0.0311445,
0.0370913,0.0436378,0.0507843,0.0579272,0.0669387,0.0778145,0.0905629,
0.103309,0.117888,0.134298,0.152544,0.170798,0.189057,0.206303,0.222534,
0.23775,0.252964,0.268183,0.283408,0.297553,0.310615,0.322596,0.334586,
0.346587,0.358596,0.370278,0.381626,0.392649,0.403679,0.412966,0.420502,
0.426288,0.432074,0.437862,0.443651,0.448986,0.453863,0.458279,0.46269,
0.467095,0.470992,0.474378,0.477252,0.480125,0.482991,0.485854,0.488778,
0.491768,0.494822,0.497876,0.502303,0.505044,0.507866,0.509265,0.510464,
0.511369,0.51204,0.512616,0.51319,0.513758,0.514338,0.514918,0.515905,
0.517295,0.519157,0.521105,0.52315,0.52523,0.527329,0.529441,0.531565,
0.534286,0.537608,0.541534,0.546153,0.551458,0.557451,0.563453,0.569467,
0.575485,0.58312,0.59236,0.603189,0.613984,0.635441,0.646097,0.658031,
0.685707,0.715436,0.731621,0.765757,0.78281,0.815485,0.842481,
0.855269,0.880847,0.893636,0.91831,0.92928,0.949413,0.959497,
0.969594,1.,1.,1.,1.};

NArgMax[BSplineBasis[{3, U}, #, x], x] & /@ Range[1, 110]

(*  {-6.96782,-6.96782,0.0119939,0.0165329,0.0210818,0.0260265,-6.96782,
  0.0374016,
 0.0438958,0.050987,0.0587446,0.0679349,0.0786408,0.0908766,0.104096,
 0.118843,
0.135094,0.152704,0.170715,0.188626,0.205784,0.222104,0.237665,0.252966,
0.268094,0.282946,0.296996,0.310156,0.322511,0.334591,0.346563,0.358458,
0.37011,0.38149,0.392473,0.402905,0.412026,0.419731,0.426147,0.432075,
0.437824,
0.443456,0.448749,0.453666,0.458239,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,
-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,0.48588,0.488811,0.491795,0.494937,-6.96782,
-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,0.512607,
 0.513189,0.513762,0.514371,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,0.519238,0.521148,
0.523172,0.52524,0.527336,0.529495,0.531829,0.534608,0.537935,0.541891,
0.546514,-6.96782,-6.96782,-6.96782,0.5696,0.576193,0.583977,0.59306,
0.604126,0.616939,0.632554,0.646816,0.66453,0.686672,0.712298,0.735337,
0.762662,0.786454,0.813548,0.837907,0.857441,0.878478,0.895491,0.91522,
0.930455,0.94651,0.960092,0.974142,0.988382} *)
```

In general, the relative values should be in the interval [0,1]. Obviously, the builtin gives the wrong results? In addtion, it takes much time.

So is there any fast method to compute the maxima-arguments?

**Update**

Although adding the constrint "0<=x<=1" could deal with the above proble, however, it is time-consuming when executing it just once. And in fact application, I need to execute it about 10-100 times.

[image]

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @corey979 I need the corresponding maxima position as the parameter values, then feed it to other function:)

Comment: Try `NArgMax[{BSplineBasis[{3, U}, #, x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x] & /@ 
 Range[1, 110]`, or `NMaximize[{BSplineBasis[{3, U}, #, x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x] & /@ 
 Range[1, 110]` might be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give good starting points to `FindMinimum`, it's pretty fast (thanks to the OP for a considerable improvement):

```
maxima = FindArgMax[BSplineBasis[{3, uuu}, #, x],
      {x, uuu[[# + 1]], uuu[[# + 1 + 3]]}] & /@ Range[1, 110]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.023998, Null}  *)
```

Visualization:

```
ListPlot[Flatten@maxima, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The maxima are steadily increasing, so it looks like a pretty good result.

Comment: Thanks for your fast method. In fact, to my knowledge, for the i-th B-spline basis $N_{i,p}(x)$ of degree $p$, whose valid interval should be $[x_i,x_{i+p+1}]$. Namely, the starting point could be setted to $x_i$. Thanks a again:)

Comment: @newer Thanks for the accept.  You might want to avoid the very edge of the support. My way attempted (in a rather unclever way) to get two points near the "middle."  One would probably run into trouble if the points get outside the support of the function.

Comment: So I think the above code could be revised to `FindArgMax[
   BSplineBasis[{3, U}, #, x], {x, U[[# + 1]], U[[# + 1 + 3]]}] & /@ 
 Range[1, 110]`.

Comment: @newer Yes, that is probably better.

Comment: In addtion, I am so sorry for that I cannot upvote to this good answer owing that I have the upvote-privilage.:)

Comment: @newer Thanks, anyway.  If you continue to participate on the site, you will soon get that privilege.